# Javascript mouseenter event only fires if cursor is moving fast enough

Tags: javascript, mouseenter

I'm creating a custom cursor "trailer" (see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/alexdlf/hx6yzu4w/)

Normally, the circle (`.cursor`) should trail the cursor. While hovering the red box (`.cl`), the circle should move and stick to the tiny blue point (`.ct`) within the red box. This is triggered by a `mouseenter` listener. However, if the cursor is moved into the red box too slowly, it seems the event is not firing and the effect is not taking place (it works fine if the cursor enters the red box at a normal/faster speed).

Is there something wrong with my implementation? Or is there something fundamental about `mouseenter` that I'm missing?

Comment: You have applied transition `transition: all 0.7s ease-out;` where you set the speed. See - https://jsfiddle.net/az5fbkop/

Comment: Even in your example, moving the cursor too slowly does not trigger the snap effect (try moving your cursor over the red box as slowly as possible—the circle still sticks with the cursor until you move faster)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "cursor" is covering the red box. Having a transparent background doesn't prevent this. It "works" if you move your mouse faster than the "cursor" can keep up.

Add `pointer-events: none` to the CSS of the "cursor".